# Accessing the store from model function in routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to be able to set my model dynamically depending on a record in the store - mainly because I want to control whether or not a form submission should be a POST or PUT.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    let bankAccount = this.store.get('bankAccount').objectAt(0);

    if (bankAccount.is_connected) {
      bankAccount = this.store.createRecord('bankAccount', { account_label: 'new' });
    }

    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      appState: this.get('appStates').currentAppState(),
      user: this.store.findAll('user').thenGetFirst(),
      bankAccount: bankAccount,
    });
  },
});
```

The issue is that `let bankAccount = this.store.get('bankAccount').objectAt(0);` return null when I refresh the page.

However, if I run `App.store.get('bankAccount').objectAt(0)` in my browser console, it returns the correct record.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The store has no get method do you mean to use `findAll` to get the accounts?

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    // A better way to do this would be to `findRecord` with an id
    return this.store.findAll('bank-account').then(bankAccounts => {
      let bankAccount = bankAccounts.get('firstObject');
      // Properties are usually camel cased this seems weird
      // Can you add your model definition?
      if (bankAccount.get('is_connected')) {
        bankAccount = this.store.createRecord('bank-account', { account_label: 'new' });
      }
    });

    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      appState: this.get('appStates').currentAppState(),
      // A better way to do this would be to `findRecord` with an id
      user: this.store.findAll('user').thenGetFirst(),
      bankAccount: bankAccount,
    });
  },
});
```

On a side note your code needs some major cleanup and rethinking, especially if you are going to be dealing with people's financial data.